# Bad aspect of template implementation of matrix

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I implemented template matrix class like this.

```
template<typename T, int NRows, int NCols>
class MatrixMN;
```

But now I doubt that that implementing matrix with template was right choice for the following reason.

#### 1. `operator*=` cannot be defined

That is because ***= operator** for matrix multiplication might return a matrix  type with different dimensions.

Different dimensions means different type in template implementation.

#### 2. Arithmetic operators cannot be defined for two MatrixMN with different `T` parameter

Let's define a binary operator for matrix multiplication.

```
template <typename T1, int NRows1, int NCols1, typename T2, int NRows2, int NCols2>
MatrixMN<??, NRows1, NCols2> operator*(const MatrixMN<T1, NRows1, NCols1> &m1, const MatrixMN<T2, NRows2, NCols2> &m2)
```

`T1` and `T2` might be {`int` and `double`} or {`double` and `int`}.

So I cannot decide `T` param of returned `MatrixMN`.

I came up with some workarounds.

- forcing returned `MatrixMN` to have floating-point data type like `double`
- just do not define operators for two different `T` params.

But none of those can solve the problem perfectly...

---

Was it wrong to implement matrix class like that?

Comment: 2. `std::common_type` to find type of result + SFINAE to disallow multiplying bananas with oranges?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot `std::common_type` works for me. Thanks! But I need to search more to get the concept and usage of SFINAE.

Comment: IMO, yes it is a bad choice to use dimensions as template arguments, generally speaking.  Templates are best suited for the enablement of algorithms and data containers to be type-agnostic in their definition, yet type-safe in their usage/instantiation, which is why the template arguments are typically types (not integer constants).  I would recommend that your matrix not use templates and accept dynamic dimensions provided as constructor inputs, unless you have a compelling special reason not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit `operator*` to only work on matrices of the same type and you know the resulting size: m-by-n multiplied by n-by-k results in an m-by-k matrix. Put it together and you get:

```
template<typename T, int M, int N, int K>
MatrixMN<T, M, K> operator*(const MatrixMN<T, M, N> &lhs, const MatrixMN<T, N, K> &rhs)
```

If you want to allow implicitly convertible types only then use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
// Arithmetic operation allowing for implicitly convertible types
template<typename TL, typename TR, int M, int N, int K>
MatrixMN<typename std::common_type<TL, TR>::type, M, K> operator*(
        const MatrixMN<TL, M, N> &lhs,
        const MatrixMN<TR, N, K> &rhs)
```

If you want to allow any combination of types that you define, that's what `traits` are for:

```
template<typename LHS, typename RHS, typename RES>
struct MatrixMNBinaryTraitsBase {
    typedef LHS TypeLeft;       // Element type of left hand side
    typedef RHS TypeRight;      // Element type of right hand side
    typedef RES TypeMultResult; // Element type of matrix multiplication
};

// Base case: support for implicitly convertible types
template<typename TL, typename TR>
struct MatrixMNBinaryTraits : MatrixMNBinaryTraitsBase<TL, TR, typename std::common_type<TL, TR>::type> { };

// Special case Foo x Bar -> Foobar
template<>
struct MatrixMNBinaryTraits<Foo, Bar> : MatrixMNBinaryTraitsBase<Foo, Bar, Foobar> { };

// Arithmetic operation allowing for different types according to MatrixMNBinaryTraits
template<typename TL, typename TR, int M, int N, int K>
MatrixMN<typename MatrixMNBinaryTraits<TL, TR>::TypeMultResult, M, K> operator*(
        const MatrixMN<TL, M, N> &lhs,
        const MatrixMN<TR, N, K> &rhs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your operator can be defined for matrices with both the good dimensions and the good underlying types (ie `T1` and `T2` such that there is a valid `operator*` taking `T1` and `T2` and its type has a defined `operator+`.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
using multiply_type = decltype(std::declval<T1>()*std::declval<T2>());

template <typename T1, typename T2, int N, int K, int M>
auto operator*(Matrix<T1, N, K> const& m1, Matrix<T2, K, M> const& m2)
    -> Matrix<multiply_type<T1, T2>, M, N> {
    /* Implementation of the product */
}
```

This is less restrictive than the `std::common_type`, though you are not very likely to build matrices on non arithmetic types (but what if?)

This technique can be seen running on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d735464f80fbd201).